# HTML src not correctly accessing required filepath

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have included a folder where I keep files I don't want people easily looking at, like passwords in php connection files.  This folder is called 'inc' and is at the same level as the 'public_html' folder.  I have put php files with database connection details in the 'inc' folder and accessed this using '../inc/' and the filename and it works perfectly - i.e.:

```
require_once('../inc/connection.php');
```

I would also like to put javascript files in the 'inc' directory and access them via the src path in HTML.  I have tried the same approach as with the php file - that is using '../inc/' and the file name to access the files and for some reason it is not working:

```
<script src="../inc/moment.js"></script>
```

I have read similar queries to this on Stack Overflow and followed the right approach (locally and on server) but for whatever reason it is not accessing the js file.  It does work however if I relocate the 'inc' folder to within the 'public_html' folder (for js files only) but this defeats the purpose of what I am trying to achieve - and in my mind should not work.

Does php treat the access of directories different to HTML's src hence different behaviour using '../'.  I don't think it should and yet I can't get it to work.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you give permission to access that folder?

Comment: Have you tried using a complete path?

Comment: Try `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/from/root'` on the include

Comment: That directory is named `public_html`, because you are supposed to put everything that you want to be _publicly_ available on the web in there. _“I would also like to put javascript files in the 'inc' directory and access them via the src path in HTML.”_ - that is not possible. Your system was deliberately set up this way, that stuff in `public_html` is available via HTTP on the web - and everything else outside of that folder isn’t. // Why do you want this in the first place? Are you under the impression that you could “protect” your JavaScript code that way? Of course you can’t.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I now understanfd my error.  All sorted now!

Answer (score 0):

A script tag with a source attribute is html that tells the browser to go get a file. Relative paths can be used, but your js files will need to be accessible to the public; they simply can't be hidden outside of the public root.

PHP is a scripting language running on your server. When it sees ../ in the proper contexts, such as the require_once directive you mention, it translates that into the proper path to the directory you are looking for, so it can look outside of the public directory.

Don't put sensitive items in the js, put them in protected files on the server. If you need the info at runtime, make an ajax call to access and use the data to provide the client with only the information it needs.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response - it is now clear why it wasn't working for me.  I had assumed I could use that folder like I had done with the php file.  I have now updated my files and structure accordingly - thanks again!